# Java and WCF Inter-portability issue with DateTime

Tags: java, c#, wcf, datetime

I built a .NET WCF service with Data Contracts that have DateTime members. When the client uses eclipse to auto generate the proxy classes the generated classes have them as Calendar not Date so the time gets sent to the service in GMT which shifts the actual value by 8 hours (Difference between GMT and PST). The client has already built an application around those proxies and are in the late phases of QA so they want to fix this problem with minimal changes to their app i.e no changes to the method signatures of the web service.
Is there anyway I can decorate the DateTime member so its gets translated to the correct Date data type in java.

Any other suggestion to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found that calling ToLocalTime() on the DateTime member will remove the 8 hours difference.